# Unit testing in Angular & Jasmine WITHOUT KARMA

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am supposed to write unit tests in an Angular project by using Jasmine & Karma, but I was asked to use only Jasmine without Karma, is there any documentation so i can make that works without Karma ?

Documentation && explanation

Comment: Everything is described in the jasmine documentation. Please perform proper research before asking such questions on stack overflow. If you have a **specific** problem or question, you can ask a new question.

Comment: It seems that the Angular team is going to get rid of `karma` as well. `To that end, we will integrate Web Test Runner with Jasmine to provide a testing experience extremely similar to the current Karma setup. We will also provide `ng update` support for migrating existing Karma tests to Web Test Runner.` When it is going to happen, I am not sure. https://blog.angular.io/moving-angular-cli-to-jest-and-web-test-runner-ef85ef69ceca